# Where to get specification for keep-alive in sockets in .NET?

Tags: .net, sockets, keep-alive

I'm trying to find out how exactly keep-alive works in .NET but link from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e160993d.aspx) doesn't work. Could anybody post a link with specification?

**What I'm looking for:**

- I would like to know how often are the keep-alive packets sent.
- Do I have to set KeepAlive via command:

  s.SetSocketOption (SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);

  only at the server side or even the client has to set this flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure this is what you are looking for, but the `SocketOptionName` enum has a `KeepAlive` member, as can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname.aspx).

From the documentation, you would use it this way:

```
s.SetSocketOption (SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know how often are the keep-alive packets sent. And this is what would like to see in the documentation.

Comment: @MartyIX - The default according to RFC 1122 is 2 hours, and this is how windows is setup. See this blog post - it is a global registry setting. http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2666745.php

Comment: I found it on MSDN too (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee470551(VS.85).aspx). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have a [writeup on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) about keepalives. Short answer: both sides need a keepalive of some kind, but if you have a "poll" initiated from one side, then that can act as a keepalive. Also, I recommend building the keepalive right into the protocol rather than using the socket setting.

On my blog entry I don't go into a great deal of detail about the keepalive socket setting, because I believe it's not very useful (see the blog post for details).

Note that the "global registry setting" was changed with Windows 2000. It now *can* be changed on a per-connection basis. I still don't recommend it as a keepalive, though (see my blog post for details).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Interesting and useful!